# What does Fortitude Immunity include?

Tags: immunities, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

According to Mutants & Masterminds 3e RAW would a flat Immunity to Fortitude Checks include immunity to:
suffocation, thirst and starvation and sleep?

The Player insists that it does, and hopes to use it for his "Heroic Zombie Hero."

His character is essentially [the construct](http://www.d20herosrd.com/character-creation/archetypes/construct/), but the undead revenant variant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes

Because Immunity provides automatic success on relevant resistance checks (Hero's Handbook page 113), and because Suffocation (Hero's Handbook page 186) and Starvation and Thirst (Hero's Handbook page 186) are resisted with Fortitude checks, immunity to Fortitude does protect the character from suffocation and starvation and thirst.

> **Immunity:** You are immune to certain effects, automatically succeeding
>   on any resistance check against them.
>
> **Suffocation:** After that time they must make a Fortitude check (DC 10)
>   each round to continue holding their breath. The DC increases by +1 for each previous success.
>
> **Starvation & Thirst:** After this, they need to make a Fortitude check (DC 10, +1 per previous check) ... to avoid a level of fatigue.

### and Maybe

Sleep is a different problem. There are no rules about resisting the biological need for sleep, aside from the Rank 1 Immunity. Immunity (Fortitude) would make the character immune to sleep effects resisted by Fortitude resistance checks, such as the sample Sleep power (Hero's Handbook page 129), but not to sleep effects resisted by Will resistance checks. 
 So, whether or not the character needs to sleep depends upon GM adjudication, specifically about what checks are required to resist falling asleep outside of power effects. Arguments can be made for both Fortitude and Will checks, and ultimately you'll have to choose the answer that is the most fun for your table.

Personally, I don't see why his not sleeping is a problem. Being awake doesn't make you alert, as proven by real life bored and inattentive guards or phone-distracted pedestrians walking into traffic.

Answer (score 4):

It includes any *Resistance* check related to your immunity, as described by the power's description:

> You are immune to certain effects, automatically succeeding on any resistance check against them.

So if your character has to make a Fortitude check to avoid getting poisoned or diseased, you automatically succeed that check and avoid any damage or penalty associated with it. Similarly, with 30 ranks, you become immune to anything that asks for a Fortitude or Will check.

On a smaller and less subjective scale, you can obtain immunity to certain damage types, like cold, electricity, fire or even magic. Being immune to fire, for instance, would automatically avoid any damage caused by fire sources, be them mundane or of superpower origin.

Keep in mind that a **Resistance Check** is a check to avoid the effects of powers and other sources of damage or negative effects on your character (pg 16):

> A resistance check is an attempt to resist different effects, ranging **from damage and injury to traps, poisons, and various power effects**. A resistance check is a d20 roll + the appropriate defense (typically Dodge, Fortitude, Toughness, or Will).

There is a note on page 113 discussing the problems with *Immunity* and how the GM can fix it:

> **Under the Hood: Immunity**
>
> There are characters in comic books flatly immune to certain things. Immunity is intended to provide this option in Mutants & Masterminds. It’s simpler at some point to say a character is immune to something than it is to bother rolling dice. Immunity also encourages creativity: if you can’t overcome a foe just by hitting him, what then? Encourage players to use tactics, cleverness, power stunts, and hero points to deal with foes immune to their more conventional attacks.
>
> If you find Immunity—especially broad immunities at higher ranks—a problem in your game, feel free to restrict it (perhaps to no more than 10 ranks) or eliminate it altogether, replacing it with Protection and defense bonuses with appropriate power modifiers.